# Rest api on Rails 

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am in need of creating a rest api for syncing data with my mobile app.Although I am more acquainted with java I am learning Ruby on Rails currently and it has caught my interest.

Here are my present requirements for creating the rest api.

(1)Send message to the server when the app is started .

(2)Username password authentication.

(3)Get all rows present in a table if a condition is satisfied.

(4)Delete,Update and Insert Operations.
   I would be sending the request for all these operations on a single button click.So the   request might go together

My question Would it be best to build the rest api in rails considering the above requirements and the time to learn it or should i just go with java play framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making that app should be relatively easy to do in Rails. However, your question

> My question Would it be best to build the rest api in rails considering the above requirements and the time to learn it or should i just go with java play framework?

is subjective. A Rails developer would likely tell you to do it in Rails because those are the things Rails is good at.

From a biased point of view: **Yes, learn Rails and implement it.** Take it with a grain of salt though as I'm not familiar with how easy it is to do a web app in Java.

**UPDATE**: I had found this [article in the Miso blog](http://engineering.gomiso.com/2011/05/16/if-youre-using-to_json-youre-doing-it-wrong/) that will help you implement an API. I haven't tried it but it definitely looks interesting, and their points seem quite valid.

Comment: Thanks Ramong.I have started with rails and moving along.

Comment: I added a link to an article about how to make an API easily according to the Miso guys.

Comment: Thanks.I am gonna go through it.